# chart x-axis data is not visible when more than 10 point

Tags: c#, charts, asp.net-charts

chart x-axis data is not visible when more than 10 point:

```
chart.ChartAreas.Add("chart1");
                chart.Series.Add("s1");
                for (int i = 0; i < dtRpt.Rows.count; i++)
                {
                    string i1=dtRpt.Rows[i]["vchCompetency"].ToString();
                    float i2 = float.Parse(dtRpt.Rows[i]["Average"].ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat); 
                    chart.Series[0].Points.AddXY(i1, i2);
                }
```

Its my chart code;how to overcome by this problem ;any other method is there. i tried for `chartarea.AxisX.IntervalType` its not working for string value.Any help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

OT: Why not use the `DataBindTable` or `DataBindCrossTable`? Its cleaner and faster.

It's better practice to set the DataType of axis

```
Chart1.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.[type]
```

instead of passing everything as a string. That way the chart control don't have to guess and usually this create less problems.

(Actually you retrieved the value as a string from the DataTable and casted into float - wicked!)

You might wanna check the `Chart1.AxisX(or Y).Interval` property instead of `Chart1.AxisX(or Y).IntervalType` to display more specific chart. Usually the Interval is set by default accordingly to the amount of data to be shown.

Comment: You can see my previous post;i used Chart1.AxisX(or Y).Interval and  checked with  DataBindTable.but i am getting same problem

Comment: 1)too many posts with informations scattered all around Stack Overflow

2)try to round the float using `Math.Round(number_to_round,2)` and pass it like that in the x datapoint

3)try to set `Chart1.Height = 600; Chart1.Width = 800;`

Also it is not very clear what do you mean by 'is not visible when more than 10 point'

Comment: Actually i found the problem is if more than 10 points my chart is not coming proper.its not the reason point value i am passing.